# AVAudioPlayer not stop automatically when enter background in iOS 8.2~8.3

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Our app play some sounds. But we don't want to play in background.

We found only iOS 8.2~8.3 won't stop sound when app enter background.

Is this a bug or AVAudioPlayer have changed in iOS 8.2~8.3?

Comment: try viewWillDisappear  if you want it on ViewController level , or create AVplayer shared instance and stop in applicationDidBecomeActive method

Comment: Thank you. Yes we can stop sound in applicationDidEnterBackground manually. But we want to know what happen in iOS 8.3 .

Comment: Info.plist backgroundMode enabled for audio?

Comment: No. Same code work fine until iOS 8.2. (I download iOS 8.2 simulator same problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this is a bug with simulator from iOS 8.1 ~ 8.3.